# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Mentors#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this error coming up When I add a new teacher to the platform, which I called "Mentor".

[image]

It was all working fine until I did two things:

- added the stripe payment to the mentor profiles
- added and then removed the user friendly id gem from the mentor profiles as it was causing me issues in the next steps.

here is an extract from my show.html.erb page related to the stripe payment

```
    <%= form_tag call_path(slug: @mentor.slug) do %>
    <script
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
      data-amount="<%= (@mentor.price * 100).floor %>"
      data-name="Find a Teacher"
      data-description="<%= @mentor.name %>"
      data-email="<% current_user.email %>"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-zip-code="true"
      data-currency="gbp">
    </script>
  <% end %>
```

Here is how my transaction controller looks like:

class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

```
def create
    mentor =  Mentor.find_by!(slug: params[:slug])

    sale = mentor.sales.create(
        amount: (mentor.price * 100).floor,
        email_user: current_user.email,
        email_mentor: mentor.user.email,
        stripe_token: params[:stripeToken]
        )
    sale.running!

    if sale.completed?
        redirect_to pickup_url(guid: sale.guid)
    else
        redirect_to mentor_path(mentor), notice: @error
    end
end


def pickup
    @sale = Sale.find_by!(guid: params[:guid])
    @mentor = @sale.mentor
end
```

end

I'm not sure if these two extracts would be enough to understand the issue, I'm quite new to ruby and coding overall. Please let me know if I'd need to provide more information to solve this.

I added the routes.rb file in below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :mentors do
    resources :reviews
  end

  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  get 'bementor' => 'pages#bementor'
  get 'dashboard' => 'pages#dashboard'
  post '/call/:slug', to:'transactions#create', as: :call
  get '/pickup/:guid', to:'transactions#pickup', as: :pickup 
end
```

Comment: `@mentor` or `@mentor.slug` is `nil` try debugging the variable to see if takes the needed value.

Comment: Hi @SebastiánPalma, thanks for your answer. I'm not quite sure why this error wasn't occurring before. Also,  I'm not entirely sure how to do debugging :( I'm new to ruby. Thank you

Comment: Check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html), and when the view renders see your console.

Comment: please provide your routes.rb file, @Lily

Comment: Hi @Galih, I've added the routes.rb file to the initial question summary. Thanks very much. Lilija

Comment: Solved the issue. I forgot to replace slug with id within the payment process when I removed the friendly URL from the application.